# How to remove old revisions product?

Tags: commerce

How to remove old revisions product? I have a lot of old revisions of products. They must be removed. How?

Comment: Why must they be removed?

Answer (score 3):

Drupal Commerce does not provide a UI nor function for this actually. However, we can look at how the Node module does it and run the same function, just adjusted.

From `node.pages.inc`, there is a function to delete a specific Node revision.

But that is only for a specific revision ID. Here's an adjusted function that loads a products revisions and purges them.

```
/**
 * Deletes a node revision.
 *
 * @param $revision_id
 *   The revision ID to delete.
 *
 * @return bool
 *   True on success, false if not.
 */
function commerce_product_revision_delete($revision_id) {
  if ($revision = entity_load('commerce_product', NULL, array('revision_id' => $revision_id))) {
    $revision = reset($revision);
    // Prevent deleting the current revision.
    $commerce_product = commerce_product_load($revision->product_id);
    if ($revision_id == $commerce_product->revision_id) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    db_delete('commerce_product_revision')
      ->condition('product_id', $revision->product_id)
      ->condition('revision_id', $revision->revision_id)
      ->execute();
    field_attach_delete_revision('commerce_product', $revision);
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Basically the trick is ensuring you load the revision and then delete it's record and invoke `field_attach_delete_revision` so the old field data gets purged.

I created an issue in the queue for this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2660056

Comment: I implemented this functionality in a module, [Commerce Product Revision Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_revision_delete),
using the code provided by Matt Glaman.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to remove any entity revision, the [entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) provides a helper function:

```
entity_revision_delete($entity_type, $revision_id);
```

Which you can call like this:

```
entity_revision_delete('commerce_product', 6);
```

Where `6` is the revision ID of the product you want to delete.

[Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) includes a revision delete option, which you could use to create a view that looks at product revisions and allows you to delete them in bulk.

Comment: Drupal Commerce does not implement `revision deletion callback` callback or controller method, so unfortunately we can't piggy back this.